# Reduced battery life in my netbook

Tags: power-management, battery

I notice my battery is getting empty quickly while using Ubuntu 11.10. When I am using Windows 7 with the same power settings and usage, I get a back up of around 3 hours whereas in Ubuntu it is half. Can you please advise how to increase battery life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the jupiter power management applet. I'm getting ~4 hours.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html

It says you need to use a hack or something in the instructions, but I just added the ppa, updated, installed, and restarted unity or logged out and in again (I cant remember which), and I'm pretty sure it just worked.

If not, you may have to whitelist it, but it should do that on its own I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Linux kernel 3 (> 2.6.38) has some power issues. This should be fixed soon, meanwhile there's a fix you can try: [Fix power issue](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/linux-kernel-power-issue-fix.html).

BTW, your laptop has hybrid graphics tecnology (ex: NVidia Optimus)?

Comment: Are you mentioning sudo nvidia-settings ? I have tried but seems it is not there.

Comment: You can check with this command:  lspci -vnnn | grep VGA.







If you got 2 graphics cards, your laptop has that technology. If you have that, you should check Bumblebee project (NVidia Optimus) or http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com