# Battery Life on a Lenovo ideapad u410 ultrabook

Tags: 12.04, battery, lenovo, temperature, ideapad

I have bought a Lenovo Ideapad u410 last week. Normally I only use Ubuntu, so I tried to install it. After a few (or a few more ;) ) hours I got it working. I used both systems, Ubuntu and Windows, without problems. Now my Windows system dosen't boot anymore, but that is another story...

Today I noticed that the battery life is **only about 3 hours** (the u410 should have a battery life of about 9 hours!). Also the ultrabook gets **very, very hot.**

Does anyone know how I can increase the battery life and handle this "gets too hot" thing?
I'm really concerned about my new baby =)

Comment: Try referring [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79328/reduced-battery-life-in-my-netbook).

Comment: Take a look at this for battery optimization: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147094/what-power-settings-can-i-use-for-asus-u32u-es21-to-achieve-something-close-to-t/147144#147144

Answer (score 1):

Try:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks

and also:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/IdentifyingIssues

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
sudo powertop
```

Other people report it too, not much help in certain faq-like forums. 
http://communities.intel.com/thread/30526

I'd check first of all if it's related to the power regression issue 3.4-3.5, it seems to affect other Lenovos too (related to some very old chips in those new systems). Try running `powertop` after killing X to see if it is graphics related. It could also be connected to RC6-states not being activated like they should. 
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE1MTI

Don't use conservative CPU scheduler, on-demand is recommended as the appropriate by Intel and all other authoritative sources. The names are a bit misleading, just run on-demand on such a laptop.

This laptop has both the discrete Intel GPU and an Nvidia GPU, try deactivating one of them and check for power consumption.

I advise you to create a proper bug report for this issue instead of using askubuntu.com - most advice in here is not so qualified. Such a large power consumption as in the U410 on Ubuntu current is not an issue of tweaking power settings - it signifies some actual defect somewhere. Relatedly, do you also experience issues with the built-in microphone?

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:artfwo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

When you reboot your system there will be an icon on the tray. Select the conservative plan for your cpu.